# apache mod_rewrite change base-url in deeplinks

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, forward

The whole URL of my system is changing, as it is moved to a different location. I'd like to use my old Apache to forward 301 all calls to the new system for some time.

I have deeplinks like this:

```
https://old.example/groups/something
```

which will stay the same on the new system - but with a different base-url, so like:

```
https://new.example/groups/something
```

I'm looking for an Apache rewrite rule that sustains everything after `old.example/` while changing the base-url part and sending the user over to the deeplink location he asked for in the new system.

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old\.example$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/$
RewriteRule .* https://new.example/ [R=301,L]
```

but this only works if the base URL is called directly, not for deeplinks.

Comment: Are you using `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old\.example$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/$
> RewriteRule .* https://new.example/ [R=301,L]
> ```

Your second *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) is specifically checking that the `REQUEST_URI` is the document root ("base URL") only. You are also not passing the requested URL-path to the target URL.

However, if the new site has moved to a "different location" and the new and old domains point to different servers then you can use a simple `Redirect` directive on your "old Apache" server to redirect everything and maintain the same URL structure. For example:

```
Redirect 301 / https://my.new.system.url.net/
```

The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL. So, a request for `/groups/something` is redirected to `https://my.new.system.url.net/groups/something`.

Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

---

*Aside:* Just a quick note on the "unique" terminology you have used to describe the URL, as it's a bit confusing...

What you call the "base-url" is really the *hostname* (or *domain name*).

And what you call a "deeplink" is really the *URL-path* (or the remainder of the URL). The URL-path starts with the first slash after the *hostname*.